# Ошибка в коде на php

Tags: база-данных, php

Добрый день! Есть кусок следующего кода:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'phpsols') or die ('Cannot open database');

$per_page = 3;

$num_pages=ceil($total_rows/$per_page);

if (isset($_GET['page']))
$page=($_GET['page']-1); else $page=0;

$start=abs($page*$per_page);

$q="'SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT $start,$per_page";

$result1=$conn->query($q);

$row = $result1->fetch_assoc()
```

Происходит ошибка на последней строке кода:

```
$row = $result1->fetch_assoc()

Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in Z:\home\localhost\www\homepage\index2.php on line 38.
```

В чем может быть ошибка? Подскажите люди...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q="'SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT $start,$per_page";
```

исправь на

$q="SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT $start,$per_page";

Из-за этого запрос к БД завершился ошибкой, а `$result1`, соответственно, не был объектом, поэтому последние 2 строки лучше заменить на вот это:

```
if ($result1=$conn->query($q))
    $row = $result1->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: сам уже разобрался, но все равно спасибо

Answer (score -1):

$row = $result1->fetch_assoc()

$row = $result1->fetch_assoc();